# Multiple css files in Wordpress child theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I made a child theme for 'Square Theme' in Wordpress and my 'functions.php' code in my child theme looks like this:

```
<?php
function square_child_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'parent_style' ));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'square_child_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

The thing is, I also want to edit another css file, that its path in the parent theme is "/css/owl.carousel.css".

So, should I create an "owl.carousel.css" file in my child theme too? And also, which code should I add to my child-theme's "functions.php"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends whether that owl css is loaded in the child theme too and what you mean by 'edit'.  Child theme normally inherits all the parent php template files, and the parent functions.php but not the base css.    So normally one has to enqueue the parent css if one wants to use it.   I imagine in this case if it's not the main css it might be being loaded anyway? (View source to check)

1) If you don't want it at all, you could use  wp_dequeue_style to get rid of it.

or

2) if by 'edit' you mean you just want to make minor modifications, you could add those minor mods to override the owl css in your own stylesheet.

Comment: It is indeed loaded anyway. But I want to make some modifications in it. How can I override the owl css in my own stylesheet (and also, by "your own stylesheet" you mean the child's style.css, right?) ?

Comment: edit: I did it like you said. I included the changes in my child theme's style.css and it worked!